# Trouble creating excel xy scatter plot in c#, specifically assigning X axis values

Tags: c#, excel, scatter-plot

I am 99% done with creating a file to execute an external program and then fetch data and run calculation and put it into an excel spreadsheet.

The final part is to create an XY scatter plot from the program.  I start the chart at the comment line //Add chart, but included the stuff before it just as reference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Generate Excel File when user clicks button
    {
        string fileTest = "C:\\Cinder\\" + titleTextBox.Text +"\\table.xlsx";
        if (File.Exists(fileTest))
        {
            File.Delete(fileTest);
        }

        Excel.Application App;
        Excel.Worksheet Sheet;
        Excel.Workbook Book;

        App = new Excel.Application();
        Book = App.Workbooks.Add();
        Sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Book.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Sheet.Cells[1,1] = "This table represents the data from " + titleTextBox.Text + "and shows the mrem/hr for times after an operation"; // row 1, column 1

        if (datatable.Checked)
        {
            Sheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Minutes after run"; //row 2, column 1
            Sheet.Cells[3, 1] = "20";
            Sheet.Cells[4, 1] = "30";
            Sheet.Cells[5, 1] = "40";
            Sheet.Cells[6, 1] = "50";
            Sheet.Cells[7, 1] = "60";
            Sheet.Cells[8, 1] = "120";
            Sheet.Cells[9, 1] = "180";
            Sheet.Cells[10, 1] = "240";
            Sheet.Cells[11, 1] = "360";
        }
        if (datatablelong.Checked)
        {
            Sheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Days after run"; //row 2, column 1
            Sheet.Cells[3, 1] = "1";
            Sheet.Cells[4, 1] = "2";
            Sheet.Cells[5, 1] = "3";
            Sheet.Cells[6, 1] = "4";
            Sheet.Cells[7, 1] = "5";
            Sheet.Cells[8, 1] = "6";
            Sheet.Cells[9, 1] = "7";
            Sheet.Cells[10, 1] = "8";
            Sheet.Cells[11, 1] = "9";
        }

        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\cinder\\" + titleTextBox.Text + "\\tables_by_grp");

        for (int i = 2; i < 11; i++)
        { 
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("  TOTAL GAMMAS/(CC-S)"))
                {
                    string[] substrings = line.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                    textBox1.Text = substrings[i];
                    Sheet.Cells[i+13, 1] = textBox1.Text;

                }

                if (line.StartsWith("   GROUP MID POINTS:"))
                {
                    string[] substrings = line.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                    textBox2.Text = substrings[i];
                    Sheet.Cells[i + 13, 3] = textBox2.Text;
                    break;
                }
            }

            double mRem;
            double gammas = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            double gammaE = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            double E = Math.Log(System.Convert.ToDouble(gammaE));

            if (gammaE <= 0.03)
            {
                mRem = 1000.0 * gammas / (4.0 * Math.PI * 30.0 * 30.0) * Math.Exp(-20.477 + -1.7454 * E);
                Sheet.Cells[i + 1, 2] = mRem;
            }

            if (gammaE  <= 0.5 & gammaE  > 0.03)
            {
                mRem = 1000.0 * gammas / (4.0 * Math.PI * 30.0 * 30.0) * Math.Exp(-13.626 + -0.57117 * E + -1.0954 * E * E + -.024897 * E * E * E);
                Sheet.Cells[i + 1, 2] = mRem;
            }

            if (gammaE < 5.0 & gammaE > 0.5)
            {
                mRem = 1000.0 * gammas / (4.0 * Math.PI * 30.0 * 30.0) * Math.Exp(-13.133 + 0.72008 * E + -0.033603 * E * E);
                Sheet.Cells[i + 1, 2] = mRem;
            }

            if (gammaE <= 15.0 & gammaE > 5.0)
            {
                mRem = 1000.0 * gammas / (4.0 * Math.PI * 30.0 * 30.0) * Math.Exp(-12.791 + 0.28309 * E + 0.10873 * E * E);
                Sheet.Cells[i + 1, 2] = mRem;
            }

        }


       // Sheet.Cells[  1   ,2] = ; not used so tile will show
        Sheet.Cells[    13  ,1] = "Total Gammas";
        Sheet.Cells[    13  ,3] = "Average Energy";
        Sheet.Cells[    2   ,2] = "mRem/hr @ 1 ft";


        Excel.Range chartRange;

    /*
        Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)Sheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(180, 30, 300, 250); //location chart pops up
        Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
      */

        // Add chart.
        var charts = Sheet.ChartObjects() as
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects;
        var chartObject = charts.Add(180, 30, 300, 300) as
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject;
        var chart = chartObject.Chart;



        // Set chart range.
        chartRange = Sheet.get_Range("A2","B11");
        chart.SetSourceData(chartRange);


        // Set chart properties.
        chart.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines;
        chart.ChartWizard(Source: "A2:B11",
        Title: "graphTitle",
        CategoryTitle: "xAxis",
        ValueTitle: "yAxis");



        Book.SaveAs(fileTest);
        Book.Close();
        App.Quit();


        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Cinder\\" + titleTextBox.Text + "\\table.xlsx");
```

Here is an example of the data I am trying to plot:

```
Minutes after run   mRem/hr @ 1 ft
20  61.69948
30  53.60822
40  51.91109
50  51.18693
60  50.77799
120 49.51441
180 48.61834
240 47.83341
360 46.38796
```

It is plotting what should be the X axis as values on the Y axis instead of making the X axis from the data I give.

How can I get the scatter plot to properly generate the X axis values?  When I select the data range in excel and make a scatter plot it looks completely fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Add in excel Chart for results
        Excel.Range oRng = Sheet.get_Range("B2", "B11"); 
        Excel.Chart ct = Sheet.Shapes.AddChart().Chart;
        var missing = System.Type.Missing;
        ct.ChartWizard(oRng, Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterSmooth, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, "x axis", missing, missing);
        Excel.Series oSeries = (Excel.Series)ct.SeriesCollection(1);
        oSeries.XValues = Sheet.get_Range("A3", "A11");

        if (datatable.Checked)
        {
            ct.ChartWizard(Source: "A2:B11",
               Title: "mRem/hr from gamma radiation",
               CategoryTitle: "Minutes After Run",
               ValueTitle: "mRem/hr");
            ct.Refresh();
        }

        if (datatablelong.Checked)
        {
            ct.ChartWizard(Source: "A2:B11",
               Title: "mRem/hr from gamma radiation",
               CategoryTitle: "Days After Run",
               ValueTitle: "mRem/hr");
            ct.Refresh();
        }
```